# efficient way to read the first 128 bytes from a socket but write the rest directly to a file

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I'm trying to download files from some service in the following way:

```
BODY="$(netcat "127.0.0.1" 61222 <<< "download|file_dir|file_name")"
SIGNATURE="$(echo -n "$BODY" | head -c 128)"
echo -n "$BODY" | tail -c +129 | dd of="$FILE_PATH" >& /dev/null
```

but this method has two disadvantages:

1. the entire body of the file must be stored in variable `BODY`.
2. this only works for text files.

Is there the efficient way to read the first 128 bytes from a socket into bash variable but write the rest directly to a file?

Comment: `head -c 128;` - head closes the stream

Comment: @KamilCuk no it does not.

Comment: Note that `echo -n "$var"` is better replaced with `printf '%s' "$var"`; see the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). Depending on exactly which environment variables are active at shell startup time (setting runtime flags that can also be modified at compile time or by explicit code calling `shopt` and `set -o`), `echo -n` on bash can print `-n` on output; and backslash-escape sequences in your variable can be honored even without an `-e`.

Comment: ...also see the excellent answer over at [unix.se] to [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113)

Comment: BTW, is the signature able to contain NUL characters? (If so, you can't reliably store it in a bash variable without base64-encoding or similar first).

Comment: `BTW, is the signature able to contain NUL characters?` - no, hex only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe using `bash`'s native TCP socket support? Files like `/dev/tcp/HOST/PORT` open sockets to the given host.

Roughly (Untested code due to lack of a test server):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/61222 # Open a socket on descriptor 3
printf "%s\n" "download|file_dir|file_name" >&3
read -r -N 128 -u 3 signature # Read 128 bytes from descriptor 3
cat <&3 >"$FILE_PATH"
exec 3<&- # Close the socket
```

Comment: This same practice could be used with a coproc running `netcat`; it doesn't strictly require `/dev/tcp`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why use a `netcat` process if you don't need to?

Comment: `/dev/tcp` is a compile-time option; not everyone turns it on. Granted, not everyone installs `netcat` either; the real reason for my note above is that the text of the answer describes `/dev/tcp` as a _solution to the problem_, when it's really orthogonal to the issue -- the issue can occur, or not, whether `netcat` or `/dev/tcp` is in use.

Comment: @Shawn how can I check for errors in this code? as usual using `if [[ $? != 0 ]]`?

Comment: @Shawn instead of `cat <&3 >"$FILE_PATH"` can I use something like `dd`, because I need the ability to specify the size of the rest body?

Comment: yes I can: `dd bs=$FSIZE count=1 <&3 > "$FILE_PATH" 2>/dev/null`

Comment: something is wrong with `dd` because when data readed from socket is greater than 65536 - on FS will be written just first 65536 bytes...

Comment: @niXman I'm not too familiar with **d**ata **d**estroyer, sorry.

Comment: @Shawn ah, is already solved using `head -c "$FSIZE" <&3 > "$FILE_PATH" 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

```
signature=$(nc .. | { head -c 128; cat > output_file; })
```

The `-c` option of `head` is non-standard, though supported in the `head` implementation of GNU coreutils. To make it more portable, `head` could be replaced by `dd`:

```
signature=$(nc .. | { dd bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null; cat > output_file; })
```